# regex and replace string

Tags: javascript, regex

Im trying to format my value accepting only digits and also replacing comma by dot, but i cant figure replace the comma by dot.

Example:

```
"4,82 €".replace(/[^\d\,]/g, '')
```

Expeted Value:
4.82

Comment: Of course it won't replace it with a dot because there are no dots in your code.

Comment: Your regex matches everything that isn't a digit or a comma, so you're replacing ` €` with nothing. But where's the replace of the `,` with the `.`?

Comment: `4,82 €".replace(/[^\d\,]+/g, '').replace(/,/, '.')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `'4,82 €'.replace(/[^0-9,]/g, '').replace(/,/g, '.');`

Also, you don't need to escape a `,`. It has no reserved meaning in `regex`

Answer (score 0):

Try handling this through two separate expressions, one to remove and the other to perform your replacement :

- Remove all non digits and commas.
- Replace all commas with periods.

This might look something like the expression below :

```
// Replaces all non-digits and commas /[^\d,]/ and replaces commas /,/
input.replace(/[^\d,]/g, '').replace(/,/g,'.`');
```

**Example**

```js
// Replace any non-digit or commas and then replace commas with periods
console.log("4,82 € -> " + "4,82 €".replace(/[^\d\,]/g, '').replace(/,/g,'.'))
// If you want to allow periods initially, then don't remove them
console.log("4.82 € -> " + "4.82 €".replace(/[^\d\,.]/g, '').replace(/,/g,'.'))
```

Comment: The problem if the user inserts a dot instead of a comma? It will be remove the dot

Comment: If you are expecting that, then you can handle it in the first replacement : `input.replace(/[^\d,.]/g, '').replace(/,./g,'.`');`. Basically ignore replacing periods in the first removal and then replace as usual. I've added an example demonstrating this approach as well.

Comment: But there is some issue, if you put "6,42".replace(/[^\d,.]/g, '').replace(/,./g,'.'), the output becimes '"6.2", is remove decimals

Comment: Sorry there was a typo in my comment. The second replacement doesn't need the `.` character included as the example demonstrates. Additionally, if you wanted to include it, you would need to place it within a character group (i.e. `[,.]`) as otherwise it would be treated as a universal character and would match everything. You would want `"6,42".replace(/[^\d,]/g, '').replace(/,/g,'.')`.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost right, just missed one small thing.

Your regex

> [^\d\,]

will replace only one non-digit or comma character and not all.

Change your regex to

> [^\d\,]+

like this

> "4,82 €".replace(/[^\d\,]+/g, '')

and it will work